# How to click on the button with text as Get the App within the website https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/download.do?id=41057284

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I want to press the green download button from this website: https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/download.do?id=41057284

using selenium chrome driver. However nothing works.

I tried searching by xpath:

```
clone_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="btn-download-file"]')
```

the selector:

```
clone_box = driver.find_element_by_xpath('#btn-download-file')
```

class names:

```
clone_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('btn btn-lg btn-success')
```

Does Not work. 
Further investigation lead me to so called frame/iframe.

following code suppose to switch it to:

```
driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_id("download-option"))
```

But it also doesn't work .

The question is, where is that frame/iframe ? and how to switch to it ?

Comment: The green button has id `get-the-app`, not `btn-download-file`. And I don't see any `<iframe>`. By the way the seconds and third attempts are not valid. `#` is for `css_selector` and `by_class_name` receive one class as parameter.

Answer (score 0):

To `click()` on the element you have to bring the element within the [Viewport](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp) inducing *WebDriverWait* for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `LINK_TEXT`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/download.do?id=41057284")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)");
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Get the App"))).click()
  ```
- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/download.do?id=41057284")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)");
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a.btn.btn-lg.btn-success[onclick^='ga']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  driver.get("https://www.wikiloc.com/wikiloc/download.do?id=41057284")
  driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)");    
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@class='btn btn-lg btn-success' and text()='Get the App']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: I tried all of them, however I get: "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: "
I also tried to increase the timeout value. No luck here.

Comment: @Ad.blu Try out the updated answer and let me know the status

Comment: So "driver.execute_script("scroll(0, 250)")" throws an error: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: call function result missing 'value'
  (Session info: headless chrome=76.0.3809.132)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.33.506120 (e3e53437346286c0bc2d2dc9aa4915ba81d9023f),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17763 x86_64). 

hmm

Comment: Hmm, you are using **chrome=76.0**, you should be using **chromedriver=76.0** but not _chromedriver=2.33_

Comment: My mistake, I corrected the version, now it runs smooth, but I cannot find the file anywhere

Comment: Also, when I execute the script, chrome driver shows this page: https://www.wikiloc.com/outdoor-navigation-app

Comment: @Ad.blu That is exactly what happens when you click on the element manually :)

Comment: I understand, but I do not want to press get the app, but rather download. 
I have written the script to log in to the website and it works. This is what I get:
https://ibb.co/w7PkPsL
How do I switch to the file tab ?

Comment: How can any contributor help you to download if downloading isn't enabled for non registered users? We don't have a visibility either to your _log in_ script or HTML after logging in.